# What is the measure of the segment AP, if $AB = 5$ and $BC = 3$?

Tags: geometry

For reference:
[image]

My progress:

[image]

$\triangle PCQ (rectangle)\\OF = R \triangle OFQ (isosceles ~rectangle) \implies FQ = R\sqrt2\\
\triangle PAO \sim \triangle PCQ \implies \frac{2R}{PA}=\frac{PC}{R}=\frac{CQ}{AO}\\\measuredangle FPC =\measuredangle FQC\\ \triangle PFQ\sim\triangle QCB $

I didn't see the usefulness of the PG semicircle

Comment: you gave $AP=3$, so there might be some letters mixing.

Comment: The diagram suggests it is BC rather than AP that is known to be $3$.

Comment: @zwim..Thanks for the alert...already fixed

Comment: @Troposphere..corrected statement

Comment: PFB   QCB  are similar triangles. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We write $AP =x$.

$\triangle APO \sim \triangle QPC$. So, $\frac{R}{x} = \frac{x+8}{2R}$

$2R^2 = x (x+8) \tag1$

$AQ = AP$ and as $BQ$ is angle bisector of $\angle AQC$, $QC = \frac{3x}{5}$

Applying Pythagoras in $\triangle ACQ$,

$ \left(\frac{3x}{5}\right)^2 + (x+8)^2 = 4R^2 = 2x (x+8) ~ $   (from $1$)

Solving for $x$, we get $x = 10$

Comment: You are the man...great...

Comment: @petaarantes From the value of $x$, we can see that $A$ is the centroid of $\triangle QPF$. We should be able to show that directly for a smarter solution. It is too late for me here but I will look into it tomorrow.

Comment: @Math..don't worry...your resolution was already great...thankful

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Triangle OHB and BQC are equal so OB=BQ this means B is midpoint of FQ and CH is coincident with CP.

If B is midpoint of FQ we have:

$\triangle BCQ\sim \triangle BFP$

Let $AP=x$ we have:

$\frac{x+5}{R\frac{\sqrt 2}2}=\frac{R\frac{\sqrt 2}2}{3}\Rightarrow R^2=6x+30$

Also $\triangle PQC\sim \triangle PAO$

Which results in:

$\frac {x+8}{2R}=\frac R x$

so we have following system of equations:

$\begin{cases}R^2=6x+30\\2R^2=x^2+8x\end{cases}$

eliminating R we get:

$x^2-4x-60=0$

which gives  $x=10$

Comment: grateful ... what guarantees that B is the midpoint of FQ?

Comment: @petaarantes, I mentioned the reason. But I think this must be included in question.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly faster. Still using the fact that $QB$ bisects $\angle AQC$, so that $\overline{CQ} = \frac35 \overline{AQ}$, by Angle Bisector Theorem, we can directly apply Pythagorean Theorem on $\triangle AQC$, which leads to
$$\overline{AQ}^2 - \frac9{25}\overline{AQ}^2 = 64.$$
Hence
$$\overline{AQ} = \overline{AP}= 10.$$